# Javascript statement meets all conditions what could be wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code meets all conditions, someone please tell me where i am going wrong; I have checked and i cant see anything wrong with the code. why are all the conditions met.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var style = $('#el_teams_TeamFormation span').html(); 
    alert (style);
         if (style = "4-4-2")
          { 
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "block";
         }
         if (style = "3-4-3")
          {
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "block";
         } 
         if (style = "3-5-2") {
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "block";
         }
         if (style = "4-5-1") {
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "block";
         }
});
```

Comment: Nothing wrong? Using assignment operator instead of a comparison operator in `if`'s condition is not wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth familiarising yourself with the different kinds of comparison operators:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Put simply, single (`=`), double (`==`) and triple (`===`) equals signs each mean different things to JavaScript.

A single `=` is an assignment operator, so in each of your if statements you're essentially asking the script to assign a value of "4-4-2" (and so on) to the variable `style` instead of comparing the two values.

If you use `==` (with type coercion) or `===` (no coercion) your code should work fine.

Comment: Something is wrong, when i put == , the codes are not executed meaning no condition is met.

Comment: @user3395611 Are you sure everything else in your code is set up correctly? I set up a Fiddle based on your code and it's working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/QD334/

Answer (score 1):

```
if (style == "4-4-2")
          { 
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "block";
         }
         if (style == "3-4-3")
          {
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "block";
         } 
         if (style == "3-5-2") {
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "block";
         }
         if (style == "4-5-1") {
            document.getElementById('footballpitch1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch3').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('footballpitch4').style.display = "block";
         }
```